# Dificuldade em listar uma nota fiscal e produtos usando PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

estou com dificuldades nesta página logo abaixo.
Minha dificuldade está em exibir os produtos de uma nota fiscal em específico. Pois no *statment*  `SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE = ?` não retorna nada! Mas quando coloco o número fisicamente (`SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE = 4519`) ele exibe normalmente!

Eis o código:

```
<code>
    include 'banco.php';
    $nota = $_GET['nota'];
    $pdoo = Banco::conectar();
    $sqll = "SELECT * FROM produtos where numnota = ?";
    $qq = $pdoo->prepare($sqll);
    $qq->execute(array($nota));
    $dataa = $qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($dataa);

    foreach ($pdoo->query($sqll)as $row) {  
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['descricao'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['unidade'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.number_format($row['qtde'],"2",",",".").'</td>';
        echo '<td>R$ '.number_format($row['valunit'],"2",",",".").'</td>';
        echo '<td>R$ '.number_format($row['desconto'],"2",",",".").'</td>';
        echo '<td>R$ '.number_format($row['total'],"2",",",".").'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    Banco::desconectar();
</code>
```

Comment: Você precisa demonstrar o problema na própria pergunta (favor [edit]), em vez de postar links com código. Veja [Posso mostrar só um link pro meu site com problemas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1913/74) e as [dicas sobre exemplo mínimo](/help/mcve).

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 1):

O problema está ocorrendo na seguinte linha:

```
foreach ($pdoo->query($sqll)as $row) {
```

Basta substitui a mesma por:

```
foreach ($dataa as $row) {
```

Olhei aqui e tem outro problema. Você quer todos os produtos de uma determinada nota. Portanto ao invés de utilizar fetch:

```
$dataa = $qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Utilize fetchAll para trazer todas as linhas:

```
$dataa = $qq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Por que o problema está ocorrendo**

Ao executar o método query ele apenas executa o seu select. Não leva em consideração a substituição de parâmetros. Por isso o recomendado é utilizar o execute. Veja uma breve descrição dos dois:

`query` executa uma instrução SQL padrão e requer que você escape corretamente todos os dados para evitar injection.

`execute` executa uma instrução preparada que permite vincular parâmetros para evitar a necessidade de escapar os mesmos.

Sua solução corrigida ficaria assim:

```
include 'banco.php';
$nota = $_GET['nota'];
$pdoo = Banco::conectar();
$sqll = "SELECT * FROM produtos where numnota = ?";
$qq = $pdoo->prepare($sqll);
$qq->execute(array($nota));
$dataa = $qq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($dataa);

foreach ($dataa as $row) {  
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['descricao'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['unidade'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.number_format($row['qtde'],"2",",",".").'</td>';
    echo '<td>R$ '.number_format($row['valunit'],"2",",",".").'</td>';
    echo '<td>R$ '.number_format($row['desconto'],"2",",",".").'</td>';
    echo '<td>R$ '.number_format($row['total'],"2",",",".").'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
Banco::desconectar();
```

Comment: Desta forma ele exibir uma sequencia de números que desconheço a orgiem. Porém vc me deu a idéia de usar a variável $qq e ele exibiu somente a última resposta da minha tabela produtos no banco...

Comment: Tinha mais uma correção a ser feita para trazer todos os valores. Veja a correção que fiz.

Comment: CASO ENCERRADO! MUITO OBRIGADO!